# How to check if the length or width of Row in a window is greater than the width of its parent window C++

Tags: c++, checkbox, mfc, cbutton

I wanted to wrap the existing text of checkbox into multiline if the width of row exceeds the width of its parent window. I am not really sure how to do that.

[The image I want to show the checkbox string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HPho.png)

[The image where the string is cropped and only shows if window is resized or maximized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuk7M.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have a problem with this I am afraid.

The setting for making a checkbox **multiline** is `ES_MULTILINE` and if you look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775464(v=vs.85).aspx) you will see that it states:

> To create an edit control using the **CreateWindow** or **CreateWindowEx** function, specify the EDIT class, appropriate window style constants, and a combination of the following edit control styles. **After** the control has been created, these styles **cannot be modified, except as noted**.

So, it would seem to me that you have three ways forward, depending on what you feel is the best or most elegant for you.

1. Set your control in the resource editor as multiline anyway. Then it doesn't matter and will wrap. No need to have to change the setting.
2. Implement the needed functionality to limit the size the window can be reduced to. I can show you how if you are interested. This way, if you set the control resize properties correctly it can resize larger but only reduce down the a known dimension (ie: the dimensions you created it in the resource editor).
3. Possibly have two controls in the same place, one as multiline and one as single. And when you decide which you want to show, swap the visibility. But I think this is a bad idea, bit of a headache, and not worth the hassle.

IMHO I would do both ideas 1 and 2 and I would happily extend my answer to provide more information.

## Update

Having looked at your images and the comments about **translations** then there is a fourth idea. If you use a third party application to manage the translations and use satellite DLL files then you can adjust the resources on a language by language basis. I sometimes have to make the default width for some windows wider due to their verbose nature.

Answer (score 0):

I have set BS_MULTILINE for the checkbox. The minimum size of the window is fixed but I just want the checkbox to fit in that. I expect it to show at least one word in the same line as other labels and remaining words in second line. So I am checking if the total width of the first row is greater than the width of window then show the string with \r\n in it else show normal string. However, I want to align first line or the first word of the checkbox with the checkbox and remaining words should come below the first word. Currently, the checkbox is in between two lines which looks weird. Is there anyway I can do this?

Comment: You should be editing your question and updating it. This is not an answer. Also, I encourage you to show screenshots of your results etc. so we can see.